# When change route material table flicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx-store

I use `ngrx@store` to handle data, and also I use `angular material table` to showing data, with search, pagination etc...

On table load, I show a message *Wait for a second...*, and after this message, I normally get data in a table, with table `pagesize="10"`. I get this data from ngrx@store

When I going on any route and came back again to this page with a table, table flicker and show all data (100+ items), and after half-second, they came back to the normal state with `pagesize="10"`

Here is how I get data from state on `ngOnInit(){...}`

```
this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserActions.LoadUsers());
this.users$ = this.store.select(fromStore.UserSelectors.getUsersAll);
this.users$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(user => { 
  this.dataSource.data = user;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Before constructor I defined

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
 @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
```

Here I showing loading message

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
  <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
    Wait for a second... data are loading...
  </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
  <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
    There is no any data...
  </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{ hide: dataSource != null }"></mat-footer-row>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{ hide: !(dataSource != null && dataSource.data.length == 0) }"></mat-footer-row>
```

Comment: Have you tried unsubscribing on ngDestroy? It seems to be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I always unsubscibe with takeUntil and alson on ngDestroy

Comment: Sorry I was away. Do one thing. Place your subscription in constructor and Loadusers on ngOnInit(). This should solve the issue. If not, then please provide stackblitz link, So that I can see into it.

Comment: Thnx, i will try tomorow when i came back to office.

Comment: Not working.... I made same "workaround" and wrap to `setTimeout(() = > this.loader = false;
        this.dataSource.data = this.newVarForAllUsers;)})` . On this way I show loader on flickering